# .nav-tabs behaving inappropriate when .navbar-brand is assigned to its sibling element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have commented out the bug(with #characters) in the navigation part of the code where I am getting the issue. Try removing the .navbar-brand as mentioned in the comment and you will get to see. 
I'm curious to know that what's happening under the hood when navbar-brand is assigned to its(element with .nav-tabs) adjacent element which conflicting with it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="author" content="NeelDUnstoppable" />
  <meta name="description" content="A rough template for html page created just for enhancing and getting a precise grip over the rules" />
  <title>html template</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

      <div class="nav" role="navigation">   

<!-- ######## Remove the .navbar-brand class from the below <a> element and the .nav-tabs class in <ul> element works completely fine ######### -->
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Blasting off with bootstrap</a>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="tickets.html">Tickets</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Stations</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row well well-lg">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>The Fastest way to space</h2>
        <p class="lead">Make your way to space in the comfort of your own rocket, elevator or transporter.</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Take the Tour</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Book Tickets Now</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <img src="images/img-header.jpg" alt="Blasting off" title="Blasting off image"/>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row text-center features">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-0">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></i> 
           <h3>Book Today</h3>
           <p>Even if you're traveling tomorrow, you can still get tickets today. We have a number of conveniently located ports around teh globe to service everyone</p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-random"></i> 
           <h3>Go Anywhere</h3>
           <p>If you need to get to space today, why not try out a transporter? Despite the claims, there are have been no deaths in the last 6weeks!</p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i>
           <h3>RocketBus&reg;</h3>
           <p>For cheapest fares, catch the next RocketBus&reg; to the stars. Cheaper on you wallet, and easiest way to make friends</p>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>

 <div class='footer'>
   <div class='container'>
     <div class='row'>
       <div class='col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-xs-6'>
         <h4>Who We Are</h4>
         <p><i>Blasting Off With Bootstrap</i> is the fastest way to space. <a href='#'>Book your ticket today</a>!</p>
         <p><a href='#'>More About Us <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right'></i></a></p>
       </div>

       <div class='col-sm-2 col-xs-6 col-md-offset-1'>
         <h4>Links</h4>
         <ul class='list-unstyled'>
           <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
           <li><a href='#'>Tickets</a></li>
           <li><a href='#'>Stations</a></li>
         </ul>
       </div>

       <div class='clearfix visible-xs'></div>

       <div class='col-sm-2 col-xs-6'>
         <h4>Stay in Touch</h4>
         <ul class='list-unstyled'>
           <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
           <li><a href='#'>Contact Us</a></li>
           <li><a href='#'>Blog</a></li>
           <li><a href='#'>Twitter</a></li>
           <li><a href='#'>Facebook</a></li>
         </ul>
       </div>

       <div class='col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-6'>
         <h4>Contact Us</h4>
         <ul class='list-unstyled'>
           <li><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-globe'></i> Orlando, FL<li>
           <li><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-phone'></i> 1-555-blast-off<li>
           <li><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-envelope'></i> <a href='mailto:#'>blastingoff@codeschool.com</a><li>
         </ul>

         <p>Blasting Off With Bootstrap &copy;2214.</p>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>


   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">     </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

The related .css file:

```
.features .glyphicon {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.row {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.quote {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #e1e1e1;
}
.quote blockquote {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
}
.quote footer {
  color: #c1c1c1;
}
section, header {
  background-color: #fff;
}
body {

}
.footer {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

/* 
#demo-nav {
  display: none;
}

.show-nav #demo-nav {
  display: block;
}
*/





/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 200px;
}
.footer {
  color: #efefef;
  background-color: #333;
}
.footer a {
  color: #9af7fe;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  body { margin-bottom: 400px; }
  .footer { height: 400px; }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to use navbar-nav instead? Tabs aren't meant for the navigation bar

Comment: @Brian No man! I wanted to use as the way it is with the .navbar-brand class being assigned to <a> element and nav-tabs class assigned to the <ul> element, and both elements being the siblings. 
I just want to know why, being both together, .nav-tabs don't behave in a normal way?

Comment: By not working, do you mean it leaves white spaces underneath or not working functionally?

Comment: @Briane Yeah by "behaving unusual" I mean that it leaves white spaces underneath and neither there exist a horizontal line underneath. I forgot to add the .css file, I am adding it now

Comment: The .navbar-brand by default has a height of 50px, which doesnt match the tabs height, thus the white spaces. You can override the navbar-brand like so:         `<a href="#" class="navbar-brand" style="padding: 11px; height: 42px;">Blasting off with bootstrap</a>` Hope this helps

Comment: Oops! Damn I could see that silly one, I just thought the horizontal line beneath it got disappeared. Thanks man! :)

Comment: No problemo. :)